# "Poetic omission" of "is" in a question

Tags: questions

I am reading "The well-spoken Thesaurus" by Tom Heehler. In the first chapter on making one's writing more poetic, the author gave an example:

> 2. Drop "is": write *"Do you think it is impertinent?"* as *"Do you think it impertinent?"*

This example confuses me as it seems like the subject in the question doesn't have a verb associated with it. It seems like I could write something like *"Do you think sky blue?"* as well. I couldn't find other examples by googling "poetic omission". Is this an acceptable practice?

Comment: I don't know about 'poetic', but it is perfectly acceptable (in somewhat formal language) to ask questions like "Do you think me stupid?" Of course, in everyday speech we would say "D'you think I'm stupid?"

Comment: It's not poetic, it's just used with verbs of perception or opinion: I find it fascinating; you consider it worth your time; they feel it a poor choice; etc.  *To be* isn't exactly omitted, it simply isn't necessary, because the verb of perception or opinion can be used there.

Answer (score 1):

The verb **is** can be used to state a fact. There are several verbs that can instead be used to express an opinion or feeling, for example find, consider, think. Here is an example:

> I find techno music boring

This is covered in the EXPERIENCE A FEELING meaning for **find** in the [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/find), which states that **find** can take an object followed by an adjective or noun. The OPINION meaning of **[consider](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/consider)** involves the same usage. **Think** can be used the same way, but it is not documented in the dictionary.

I don't think that your sentence is poetic omission at all: it's simply using a legitimate but uncommon phrasing.

As for "Do you think [the] sky blue?", if you add a definite article, it is perfectly grammatical sentence. Suppose two people had different standards for what constitutes a proper blue sky.

> A: I love the colour of the sky now: such a perfect blue.
> B: (looks up at the sky which is, in his opinion, grey-blue)
> B: Do you think the sky blue?

B could also have said

> B: You think the sky blue?
> B: Do you think that the sky is blue right now?